# в retrofit не кодируется url не полностью

Tags: kotlin, vkontakte-api, post, url, retrofit2

получаю через vkapi ссылку вида:

https://pu.vk.com/c855412/ss2192/upload.php?_query=eyJhY3QiOiJvd259

использую параметр encoded = true

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("{url}")
    fun setUrlUpload(
        @Path("url", encoded = true) url : String,
        @Part("description") description: String = "",
        @Part("photo") photo : RequestBody
    ) : Call<uploadResult>
```

в итоге ссылка становится такого вида:

https://pu.vk.com/c855412/ss2192/upload.php%3F_query=eyJhY3QiOiJvd259

в ссылке почему то не преобразует символ '?'. Как это исправить?

Comment: Заголовок с двойным отрицанием не совсем понятен. И почему символ ? не должен кодироваться раз вы сами просите его закодировать как часть URL.

Comment: Что значит заголовок с двойным отрицанием? Символ ? в не зависимости от encoded, остается 3F

Answer (score 0):

Вырезал из строки параметр запроса

```
    // загрузка аватарки
    @Multipart
    @POST("{url1}")
    fun setUrlUpload(
        @Path("url1", encoded = true) url1 : String,
        @Query("_query") url2 : String,
        @Part("description") description: String = "",
        @Part("photo") photo : RequestBody
    ) : Call<uploadResult>
```